# QT OSX Debugging loses target

Tags: macos, qt, debugging

I am aware that in general QT debugging can be a hit and miss affair, but I have got it mostly working in windows.
In OSX, I can place a breakpoint and debug it and occasionally I can then continue where as long as the system isn't in a modal dialog box (where it will hang), but if I hit step, it will hang the debugger, never return, but worse than that put the target application in an unkillable state.

Quiting QT doesn't kill it, and doing a kill 9 doesn't either. The only way I can kill the application after that is by restarting.

Although I could continue on the PC, where I can use visual studio for debugging, I would like to be able to use the mac.

This is OSX 10.9.1 running QT Creator 3.0 with QT 5.2.

I have searched around but all problems debugging appear to be getting it to actually connect to a debugger, which mine does, if only briefly.

If you don't' know how to help with the debugging issue, any info on how to kill the process when it hangs would be good too - it is very inconvenient having to restart when you hit a breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to kill the python host to the debugger. In lieu of QT fixing it